# Product topology and intersection of basis elements

Tags: general-topology, pointwise-convergence, product-space

I was wondering if you could help me settle a discussion with a co-author. Neither of us is a hard-core topologist but our current paper forced us into this, so we figured this forum was a good place to settle the discussion!

**Setting**
We are thinking of the space $\mathbb{R}^X$ where $X$ is an arbitrary set (so, all real valued functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$). We endow this with the product topology (or pointwise convergence topology). The basis we are using for this topology is the standard one, composed of sets that take the form $\Pi_{x\in X}I(x)$ where each $I(x)$ is an open set and only finitely many of these $I(x)$ sets are different from $\mathbb{R}$. Also, without loss of generality, I guess we can take the $I(x)$ sets to be intervals but that is not fundamental to the problem.

**Question**
If $D_1, \dots, D_n$ are basis elements, is their intersection. $D_1 \cap D_2 \cap \dots \cap D_n$ a basis element? (I know that in general intersection of basis elements is not a basis element, but is it for this special case?)

**Co-author 1**
This person claims YES. The idea is that intersection and product commute. Therefore
$D_1\cap D_2 \cap \dots \cap D_n = \prod_{x\in X} \bigcap_{i} D_i(x)$
Since the intersection is finite then the set $\bigcap_{i} D_i(x)$ is open, so $\prod_{x\in X} \bigcap_{i} D_i(x)$ fits the definition of basis elements. It even fits it when the sets $I(x)$ are intervals since the intersection of open intervals is another open interval (taking the convention that empty sets are intervals)

**Co-author 2**
Claims no because $\bigcap_{i} D_i(x)$ might be empty for some $x$. While we know empty sets are open this makes their head hurt. How can one think of a function such that $f(x)\in\emptyset$?

Who is right (if any, won't be the first time we get into an argument and both of us are wrong!)

Comment: Your definition does not exclude the case that any of the $I(x)$ is the empty set, so _obviously_ co-author 2 is wrong. I have a hard time seeing how this is supposed to be an actual dispute.

Comment: Yes, there is no function $f$ such that $f(x)\in\varnothing$. This tells you that if one of the $D_i(x)$ is the empty set, then that basis element happens to *be* the empty set.

Comment: @BenSteffan Well, I didn't want to make it too long. Part of the discussion boiled down to whether it was ok to include the empty set as part of the def. That was part of where the discussion got generated.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That was part of the argument. If $ \cap_i D_i(x) =\emptyset$ then  the intersection $D_1\cap ... \cap D_n$ was empty to gebin with so you get $\emptyset=\emptyset$ which is perfectly valid.

Ok, this is great. I was CA1 and I just could not get my colleague to agree to my argument so I started doubting myself! :)

Comment: Eh disregard my (now deleted) comment, I think I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The same problem occurs for any space $Z$. As a basis you can of course take all open sets. In general the intersection of two open sets can be empty. In your example, if $X$ is a singleton, then $\mathbb R^X \approx \mathbb R$ and your basis for $\mathbb R^X$ consists of all open sets of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction here. A basis $\mathscr B$ for a topology $\mathscr T$ is a subset $\mathscr B \subset \mathscr T$ such that each $U \in \mathscr T$ is a union of elements of $\mathscr B$. Equivalently, one can require that
for each $U \in \mathscr T$ and each $x \in U$ there exists $B \in \mathscr B$
such that $x \in B \subset U$.

There is no problem to allow that $\emptyset \in \mathscr B$. Okay, the empty set does not contribute to unions, thus *pragmatically* it does not make much sense to have $\emptyset \in \mathscr B$. But it is no formal issue.

Of course one can *define* a basis to be a collection of non-empty sets; it is a matter of taste.

In your example there are two approaches:

1. As a basis take all $\Pi_{x\in X}I(x)$ where each $I(x)$ is an open set and only finitely many of these $I(x)$ sets are different from $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\emptyset$ is a basis element and Co-author 1 is right.
2. As a basis take all $\Pi_{x\in X}I(x)$ where each $I(x)$ is an open **non-empty** set and only finitely many of these $I(x)$ sets are different from $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\emptyset$ is no basis element and Co-author 2 is right. However, we can say that each finite intersections of basis elements is either a basis element or empty.

In my opinion 1. is the better approach and it seems to be the "usual" one.
Actually one introduces the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) as the topology generated by sets of the form $p_x^{−1}(U_x)$, where $p_x : \mathbb R^X \to \mathbb R$ is the projection onto the coordinate $x \in X$ and $U_x$ is open in $\mathbb R$. More formally, these sets are taken as subbasis $\mathscr S$, and clearly $\emptyset \in  \mathscr S$. The finite intersections of elements of $\mathscr S$ are then a basis, and obviously this basis contains $\emptyset$.